# How to call downstream API in .Net Core using on behalf of flow?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, jwt

Net core application and react. I have react app which calls my middle tier api and middle tier api calls down stream api. I have registered three apps in azure ad. I have made all the configurations. In middle tier API I am validating the token recieved from react app and trying to get token for downstream api as below.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddTransient<DownStreamAPIService>();
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddOptions();
            var azureAd = Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd").Get<AzureAd>();
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication(Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.Authority = $"{azureAd.Instance}/{azureAd.TenantId}/v2.0";
                options.Audience = $"{azureAd.ClientId}";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateActor = false
                };
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "CorsPolicy",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
        }
```

Below is DownStreamAPIService class

```
public async Task<JArray> GetApiDataAsync()
        {
            var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

            // user_impersonation access_as_user access_as_application .default
            var scope = _configuration["DownStreamAPI:ScopeForAccessToken"];
            var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new[] { scope }).ConfigureAwait(false);

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration["DownStreamAPI:ApiBaseAddress"]);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            var response = await client.GetAsync("weatherforecast").ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var data = JArray.Parse(responseContent);

                return data;
            }

            throw new ApplicationException($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
        }
```

Below is appsettings.json file

```
 "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "c5fff990-0e0a-4bf6-9c04-79ab98e05931",
    "ClientId": "43dg8b3c-8743-4d6e-84b4-00fe04d93222"
  },
  "WebOriginUrl": "https://localhost:3000",
  "DownStreamAPI": {
    "ScopeForAccessToken": "api://723fac69-4038-4e16-92cc-3f57b7cc2381/access_downstream_api_as_user",
    "ApiBaseAddress": "https://localhost:44316"
  }
```

When I run the app I get below error

> Scheme already exists: Bearer

In my middle tier app I am validating the token and trying to obtain new token for downstream API. i am just confused weather validating token required in middle tier api or not. I am using on behalf of flow. Can soneone help if there is anything wrong in this design. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we use the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` to configure Azure AD, the project will use `Bearer` scheme to do auth. We do not need to configure it again. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#microsoftidentityweb) and [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/222e76a60930949e3e4838ece6e5ef49e793f091/src/Microsoft.Identity.Web/WebApiExtensions/MicrosoftIdentityWebApiServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27). So please remove the code

```
services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.Authority = $"{azureAd.Instance}/{azureAd.TenantId}/v2.0";
                options.Audience = $"{azureAd.ClientId}";

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateActor = false
                };
            });
```

if you want to validate the token, you can use the following code

```
 services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;

                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudiences = new string[] { "872ebcec-c24a-4399-835a-201cdaf7d68b", "api://872ebcec-c24a-4399-835a-201cdaf7d68b" },
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidIssuers = new string[] { "https://sts.windows.net/{tenantId}", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0" }
                };
            });
```